# Is there an elegant mechanism to add colour to the shell's "echo" command?

Tags: shell, colors

Does an elegant mechanism exist to add colour to the "echo" command in such a way that:

- Colours are handled for you (colours not set manually via first principles); and
- The TERM environment is taken into account; and
- The correct escape sequences are used based on the setting of TERM, including no escape sequences where colour is not supported.

For example:

```
echo-in-colour --colour=red "An error you really should care about has occurred"
```

As an alternative, is there a tool that will return the colours, again taking into account the TERM environment variable, without the need to implement anything by first principles?

```
RED=$(colour --red)
RESET=$(colour --reset)
echo "${RED}An error you really should care about has occurred${RESET}"
```

Comment: I'm doing coloring like [this](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color)